# Cannot ALTER TABLE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, heroku, readonly

I have a Hobby-Dev version of postgresql database on Heroku on which I want to run this code:

```
ALTER TABLE setting ADD show_done BOOLEAN;
```

I have been trying for hours and I still got this message:

> "Dataclip Error
>   ERROR:  cannot execute ALTER TABLE in a read-only transaction"

I am aware of this information:

https://help.heroku.com/4UIT2A5I/why-did-i-briefly-see-postgres-read-only-transaction-errors-for-my-hobby-instance

But after trying for many-many hours, I am becoming unsure if the reason of the error is some unannounced maintenance or upgrade.

Can anyone recommend any action to get over the error?

Comment: That's not a programming question; you should ask Heroku.

Comment: I added "Heroku" tag here, which means Heroku Community sees  the question and this is where Heroku itself sent me.

Comment: Of course it is cheaper for Heroku to send you here rather than help you, but it doesn't speak too well for them. How can anyone else say why your database is in recovery?

Comment: Well, I have a free account so I do not pay them anything for extra support. Still, this state of "not knowing" does not feel right after many hours of trying

Comment: After one day, still, the same message